# next-sitemap image: loc is showing as undefined in sitemap

Tags: javascript, xml, next.js, sitemap

When creating sitemap in image:loc, I am getting loc as undefined in browser when I view my xml. I need to show images present in blogs.  Also when I console.log it the link shows in terminal but shows as undefined in the browser.

Also, right now in the code I have just placed a string in loc just to see the results. I will change it once this loc is shown correctly in the browser.

Note: I have also tried using the custom Transform function(next-sitemap.config.js that comes in the library next-sitemap but it still had same results showing image: loc as undefined.

blog sitemap
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3AB9.png)

Blogs Object: (need the image shown in the data object)

```
{
  status: 200,
  data: [
    {
      _id: '6511c2cbc3ae7d1923a19a52',
      slug: 'buying-gold-in-toronto:-tips-for-local-investors',
      status: 'Publish',
      meta: [Object],
      image: 'Chapters_GTA-Page.png',
      title: 'Buying Gold in Toronto: Tips for Local AU Bullion',
      categories: [Array],
      createdAt: '2023-09-25T17:26:35.580Z'
    },
    {
      _id: '6511d646c3ae7d1923a19f5f',
      slug: 'the-2024-1-oz-gold-kangaroo-coin-from-the-perth-mint',
      status: 'Publish',
      meta: [Object],
      image: '024-kangaroo-gold-coin.jpeg',
      title: 'The 2024 1 Oz Gold Kangaroo Coin from The Perth Mint',
      categories: [Array],
      createdAt: '2023-09-25T18:49:42.943Z'
    },
  ],
  totalBlogs: 3
}
```

Index.js

```
import { getServerSideSitemapLegacy } from "next-sitemap";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import axiosInstance from "../../helper";
import { siteUrl, transform } from "../../next-sitemap.config";

export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx) => {


  const response = await fetch(
    `${axiosInstance.defaults.baseURL}/getallblogs`,
    { next: { revalidate: 3600 } }
  );
  const blogs = await response.json();
  console.log(blogs);

  const fields = blogs.data.map(({ slug }) => {
    return {
      loc: `${siteUrl}/blogs/${slug}`,
      lastmod: new Date().toISOString(),
      images: [{ loc: "image.jpg" }],
    };
  });

  return getServerSideSitemapLegacy(ctx, fields);
};

// Default export to prevent next.js errors
export default function Sitemap() {}
```

next-sitemap.config.js

```
// const siteUrl = "http://localhost:3000";

module.exports = {
  siteUrl: process.env.SITE_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
  generateRobotsTxt: true,
  sitemapSize: 7000,
  exclude: [
    "/blogs-sitemap.xml",
    "/products-sitemap.xml",
    "/checkout",
    "/cart",
    "/account",
    "/orderplaced",
    "/profile",
  ],
  transform: async (config, path) => {
    return {
      loc: path, // => this will be exported as http(s)://<config.siteUrl>/<path>
      lastmod: config.autoLastmod ? new Date().toISOString() : undefined,
      images: [{ loc: "image.jpg" }],
    };
  },
  sitemapSize: 7000,
  robotsTxtOptions: {
    policies: [
      {
        userAgent: "*",
        allow: "/",
      },
      {
        userAgent: "test-bot",
        allow: ["/path", "/path-2"],
      },
      {
        userAgent: "black-listed-bot",
        disallow: ["/sub-path-1", "/path-2"],
      },
    ],

  },
};
```

Could you please let me know how I can get the image to show properly in image:loc in sitemap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```js
  images: [{ loc: {href: "image.jpg" }}]
```

[Next Sitemap Sitemap Builder Source Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgW9n.png)

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it is showing images links in my sitemap. I am unable to upvote because I am new on stackoverflow